EF Core: can't use Include() with lazy loading
I created the data model classes and relations, created the database with EF Core. After this, I tried to use .Include() on but it can't find the table I want to include.
Model classes:
public class Client
{
     [Key]
     public int clientId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Surname { get; set; }
     public string Address { get; set; }
     public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
     public string Email { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<Reservation> reservations { get; set; }
}

public class Reservation
{
    public int reservationId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReservationDate { get; set; }
    public string ReservationStatus { get; set;}
    public virtual int clientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual int tripId { get; set; }
    public virtual Trip trip { get; set; }
}

public class Trip
{
      public int tripId { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
      public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
      public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
      public int MaxOccupancy { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Reservation> reservations { get; set; }
}

-----------------

using (var context = new HolidaysDbContext())
{
    var reservations = context.Reservations.Include(x => x.Clients); 
}

I get this error:

Error CS1061
'Reservation' does not contain a definition for 'Clients' and no accessible extension method 'Clients' accepting a first argument of type 'Reservation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I was searching the internet to solve the issue
This is my DbContext class:
public class HolidaysDbContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
     public HolidaysDbContext() { }

     protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
     {
         optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Holidays;Integrated Security=True")
             .UseLazyLoadingProxies();
     }
}


using (var context = new HolidaysDbContext())
{
var reservations = context.Reservations.Include(x => x.Client);
}

Just a typo. Use Include(x => x.Client)

I think you are mistaking the Include to include a DbSet from the DbContext, it actually refers to navigation properties on the entity being selected. So it's Include the Client on each Reservation. If it helps, the lambda expression "x" commonly used is just a declaration. Think of it like: context.Reservations.Include(reservation => resevation.Client); which should clear up why reservation.Clients wouldn't work. ("x" or "r" etc. is generally quicker to type and not as negatively received as "i" or such for things like for loops.)
